# Regular Expression to match nested curly braces

Tags: java, regex

I have String in below form :

> {1:F01ANZBSGSXAXXX166753}{2:O1030921091130DEUTSGSGXXXX28705821270911234}{3:{103:MEP}{113:NORQ}{108:10ROTRM911250002}}

I have to create a regular expression in order to get following substring from the above string :

1. {1:F01ANZBSGSXAXXX166753}
2. {2:O1030921091130DEUTSGSGXXXX28705821270911234}
3. {3:{103:MEP}{113:NORQ}{108:10ROTRM911250002}}
4. {103:MEP}
5. {113:NORQ}
6. {108:10ROTRM911250002}

> The pattern it follows is : Pattern = {key:value}  where value can
>   contain nested Pattern

I tried to form one : ({\d*:[\s\S][^}]*})
But this one fails in case of substring 3 i.e. in case of nested expression.

Comment: This looks like some sort of JSON data perhaps.  You should be using a parser to handle nested brackets, not a single regex.

Comment: See also [Regular Expression to match outer brackets](http://stackoverflow.com/q/546433/1553851)

Comment: The flagged duplicate goes into some of the theory but the short answer is that regex is the wrong tool for the job.  You need a real parser here and maybe a JSON parser can be adapted to do what you need.